# how to remove all results relating to a grouped ID when one of the results fails a test

Tags: sql, sql-server, ibm-midrange

So what I am trying to do is retrieve all of the orders from the CKDBAUDDP grouped by the KEYVADD(ID).  What I then want to do is only return the order if the status is within a certain date range.  with the code I currently have, adding another "and" with the STMPADD comparison will just remove those results from the completed query.  This is not really what I want to happen as the results just become less clear then.

```
exec('  select KEYVADD
    ,min(case when VALUADD=0 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 0"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=2 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 2"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=4 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 4"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=5 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 5"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=7 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 7"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=8 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 8"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=9 then STMPADD else null end) as "Status 9"
    ,min(nmdoh) as "Customer"
    ,min(c.scscn) as "Container"
    ,min(whsoh) as "Warehouse"
    ,min(preoh) as "Preorder"
from CKDBAUDDP a
left outer join mvpscohp h on left(a.KEYVADD,7) = h.ONHOH
left outer join mvpscnhp c on h.onhoh = c.onhcn
where whsoh in (700,711,721,731) 
    and IMGTADD = ''A''
    and KEYVADD IN (786398200,786417600)                                                                                                     
group by KEYVADD

') at nordic
```

Below is some test data retrieved from the query above.

```
KEYVADD    |            Status 0            |           Status 2            |           Status 4            |   Status 5  | Status 7  |             Status 8         |  Status 9  |     Customer  | Container  |    Warehouse | Preorder
786398200  |  2018-04-30 13:07:53.8780000   |   2018-04-30 10:21:41.9330000 |  2018-04-30 13:08:18.8560000  |   NULL      | NULL      | 2018-04-30 16:33:11.8850000  |  NULL      |  test name    |  27739742  |      721     |  N
786417600  |  2018-04-30 13:07:53.9080000   |   2018-04-30 11:21:15.7810000 |  2018-04-30 13:08:18.8930000  |   NULL      | NULL      | 2018-04-30 18:13:07.7940000  |  NULL      |  test name 2  |  27739744  |      721     |  N
```

The problem would be in this example if I didn't want the second one to show up because the status 2 was after 11 am and I put that in the And statement it would simply remove the time and put a Null in the results which is not what I want.  How would I get it to remove that ID all together?

Sorry of this is too much info but hopefully its clear what I am trying to get across.  Thanks!

Comment: It isn't too much information, in fact it is too little. What does your sample data look like and what are you trying to accomplish? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Since you are using left outer joins, that could be part of the problem as its going to bring in every row from the two tables that are left joined, possibly see if you can use inner joins, if not, you could wrap what you have as a subquery or CTE and do another select from those results where records fall within the range you want.

Comment: I suspect there is a better way than this but its hard to say without additional info.  In the meantime, I'm fairly certain you can fix this by just adding another 'AND' clause to filter out the NULL value as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would use `having`:

```
having datepart(hour, min(case when VALUADD = 2 then STMPADD end)) >= 11
```